# How to create a MVC Ext.Net project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, model-view-controller, ext.net

This is my first time using Ext.Net and I just can't figure out how to get set up.

When I open Visual Studio, do I want to make a new "Project" or "Web Site"?

Choosing "Project" gives me the option to use MVC, but I can't figure out how to use Ext.Net from there.

The little bit of information I was able to find about getting started with Ext.Net tells me to make a website so I can drag "ResourceManager" and "Window" onto a .aspx page. But then, I don't know how to make it MVC from there.

If someone could just give me the basic steps to get a blank website running, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question

[How-to setup Ext.NET 2.0 in a VS2012 MVC4 Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860727/how-to-setup-ext-net-2-0-in-a-vs2012-mvc4-project)

If you will have some problems ask again